# Find numbers which begins with a given number in a Map in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap, key

I'd like to count all keys in a HashMap which begin with a given number.
The size of each key is not always the same.
Example:

given number(long):

```
long l = 9988776655
```

find the keys (long) which begin with that number like:

```
9988776655xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

in which x stands for any integer.

How do I approach this problem? Since the length of the keys is not always the same I cannot do it with multiple modulo operations. (or can I?)

Comment: `String.valueOf(veryLongNumber).startsWith(String.valueOf(smallerNumber))`

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 5):

I'd just convert the keys to strings:

```
public static long keysStartingWith(Map<Long, ?> map, long toSearch) {
    String searchStr = String.valueOf(toSearch);
    return map.keySet().stream().filter(k -> k.toString().startsWith(searchStr)).count();
}
```

Comment: You could also use an intermediate `.map(Object::toString)` but this is likely opinion based. Else, good answer!

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the long `l` and the keys to strings. Then compare the beginning of the strings. Something like this:

```
long l = 1234L;
Map<Long, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
hashMap.put(1234567L, 1);
hashMap.put(1334567L, 2);
String longString = ""+l;
for(Map.Entry entry: hashMap.entrySet()) {
   String keyString = ""+entry.getKey();
    if(keyString.startsWith(longString)) {
        System.out.println(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: the constructor call `new String();` should not be used

Comment: I agree. I wrote this out as an example for an approach, though it is far from being the best

Comment: Also instead of `"" + somevalue` always prefer ? `String.valueOf(somevalue)`

Comment: and BTW that is not **casting** - its creating a new String (or converting into a String)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a general method, like this:

```
public static int numberOfStartsWith(Map mp, String start) {
    int count = 0;
    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        if (key.startsWith(start) count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

and overload it, like this:

```
public static int numberOfStartsWith(Map mp, int start) {
    return MyClass.numberOfStartsWith(mp, String.valueOf(start));
}
```

and

```
public static int numberOfStartsWith(Map mp, long start) {
    return MyClass.numberOfStartsWith(mp, String.valueOf(start));
}
```